# Swapping rows in a matrix to make sure each diagonal value is nonzero?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting

I have a 12x12 matrix with diagonal values that vary from being nonzero to zero, I am wondering if there is an algorithm to swap all the rows within a matrix to make sure there is no nonzero value.
My matrix C, must not have any nonzero value at C(i,i). Thoughts?

Example:
I have a 5x5 matrix

```
3 4 5 0 6
1 0 4 3 0
0 5 1 0 3
0 1 0 2 0 
2 0 5 0 0
```

How do I make it so that there are no nonzero diagonal elements?

Comment: Some examples would be useful.

Comment: Look for a perfect matching in the bipartite graph whose connectivity is determined by the nonzero entries.

Comment: It's a search problem. If a row as non-negative element at (i,j,k), then this row can be at i,j or kth position. You can use djksra algorithm to find the combination. For example [3,4,5,0,6] can be at the first, second, third or fifth row, but not at fourth row, because its fourth element is 0.

Comment: I dont follow can you provide an example? and this is only a 2-D Matrix

Comment: The pragmatic solution would be to just check all 12! row permutations. A polynomial time solution is given by David's suggestion to look for a perfect matching: Every row is represented as a node on the left side and every column is represented as a node on the right side. Connect a row node to all the column nodes where it doesn't have a zero entry. Find a maximal matching in that graph

Comment: @NiklasB. The expressions "pragmatic" and "12!" do not belong in the same sentence. haha

Comment: @TimothyShields: Well that depends how soon you want your solution ;) 12 * 12! is not too large of a number, but the algorithm will certainly take a few seconds

Answer (score 4):

1. Construct a bipartite graph.

   - Create a set of nodes, one for each row index, on the left.
   - Create a set of nodes, one for each column index, on the right.
2. For each element A(i, j) of the matrix:

   - If A(i, j) is zero, add an edge between the node for row i and the node for column j.
3. Find a perfect matching in the bipartite graph. The n edges in the matching will tell you how to permute your rows. Edge (i,j) in the matching indicates that row i should become row j.

See here for the perfect matching algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_matching#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I did some test on paper, and it seems we should add edge of A(i,j) is NOT zero?